# Ubuntu 17.04 Slow Connection Problem

Tags: wireless, internet, 17.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I installed the Ubuntu 17.04 today and the connection is very slow. Max speed is 60kbps. I did research for hours, but no results. Once back to normal, it was broken again. Everything I tried, ipv6 off, DNS changed, power saving turned off ... Please help me, internet is very important for me and there is no other connection. My computer:

iwconfig

```
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"KYKWIFI"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.32 GHz  Access Point: 4C:FA:CA:71:75:50   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

sudo lshw

```
*-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlp3s0
            version: 34
            serial: 6c:88:14:33:39:1c
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-38-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=10.57.36.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:30 memory:f1c00000-f1c01fff
```

iw wlp3s0 link

```
Connected to 4c:fa:ca:71:75:50 (on wlp3s0)
SSID: KYKWIFI
freq: 5320
RX: 30435166 bytes (53652 packets)
TX: 2970888 bytes (26332 packets)
signal: -47 dBm
tx bitrate: 54.0 MBit/s

bss flags:  short-slot-time
dtim period:    1
beacon int: 100
```

iw wlp3s0 info

```
Interface wlp3s0
ifindex 3
wdev 0x1
addr 6c:88:14:33:39:1c
type managed
wiphy 0
channel 64 (5320 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 5320 MHz
txpower 15.00 dBm
```

And I'm using dormitory internet, when connected the web page opens and you are logged in with the password.

Comment: `LANG=C sudo lshw` gives english output, I suggest you replace the Turkish one.

Comment: Technically the list is the same. Nevertheless, I changed.

Comment: Is it still slow? How were you testing the speed? Where are you located? I'm guessing not the US, but if you were it may have had something to do with a major Level 3 outage today. A bunch of my users were having connection issues this morning but it looks like it has cleared up now.

Comment: What speed are you *expecting*? 60kb/s is not unreasonable on a poorly maintaned WiFi with too many users.  Please also include the output of `iw wlp3s0 link` and `iw wlp3s0 info`

Comment: You're right, but when I connect my the phone, the speed is 5-6Mbps.